# retryWhen() not working in filter for Spring Reactive

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-retry

I'm pretty new to using Spring React and have a possibly simple issue here. I have setup a WebClient from a WebClient.Builder. Everything works totally fine except the request is not retried on a timeout.

The builder is configured with a custom filter like so:

```
builder.filter(new RetryFilter())
```

The RetryFilter looks like the following:

```
public class RetryFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

public RetryFilter() {
}

@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
    return next.exchange(request)
            .flatMap(response ->
                    response.statusCode().is5xxServerError() ?
                            response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error) :
                            Mono.just(response)
            )
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(2, Duration.ofMillis(75)))
            .onErrorMap(e -> {
                if (Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(e)) {
                    return e.getCause();
                }
                return e;
            });
    }
```

The client is used like so:

```
return client.retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .flatMap(response -> unmarshalResponse(response, input));
```

In debugging, I can see the filter being called, but I don't totally understand why the retry isn't happening.
Did I mess something up with my subscription model such that the retry is reusing the existing response without retrying? Is it something else?

Thanks!